# What's "Standarddeutsch" for "samma"?

Tags: translation, dialect, bavarian

This is from a *Tatort* TV series subtitle:

> Aber wenn du und ich da reingehen, dann **samma** ja nicht allein.

What’s the “Standarddeutsch” equivalent of *samma?*

Comment: I'd say watching the german "Tatort" crime TV series would give you a good glance about all of the german dialects. Not only all german fed-states contribute to the production of the series, but there's even a cooperation of the german ARD and the austrian ORF government financed ("öffentlich-rechtliche") broadcasting institutes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Yeah, it's hard not to like den Tatort. :)

Comment: Wird *»samma«* in einem Kontext, wie in der Frage beschrieben, auch von deutschen Muttersprachlern aus Mittel- und Norddeutschland verstanden? Ich halte das nämlich für ein Dialektwort, und wundere mich gerade, warum es in einem Untertitel verwendet wird. Untertitel sind sonst immer Hochdeutsch (nicht zuletzt auch weil es für Dialektwörter ja keine  standardisierte Rechtschreibung gibt).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Meistens. Spätestens seit "Mia san Mia" vom FC Bayern. Beim Untertitel hätte ich aber gezögert und wahrscheinlich lieber "sind wir" geschrieben. Da ist man sonst auch nicht so dialogtreu.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: It is unlikely that the Tatort “would give you a glance about all of the german dialects”. The episodes produced in Switzerland are dubbed into standard German for airing outside of Switzerland.

Comment: @Hubert Ich nehme an es war der letzte "Wiener Tatort".

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Treffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bayrisch / östereichisch *"samma"* ist eine Kurzform von *"san mia"* und ist auf Hochdeutsch gleichbedeutend mit

> sind wir / wir sind

---

*"samma"* is bavarian / austrian dialect and a short form of *"san mia"* which means

> sind wir / wir sind
>
> (english: *"we are"*)

in german standard language.

Full translation to english:

> > "Aber wenn du und ich da reingehen, dann samma ja nicht allein."
>
> But if you and me are going in there *(together)*, then **we aren't** alone.

Comment: See also Bavarian *hamma* for *haben wir*. In other regions with sloppy everyday pronunciation you would hear *hamwa* for the same. See also *Wennse wolln könnse gehn* for *Wenn Sie wollen, können Sie gehen*.